# ssh remote won't run if

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

This won't run,

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o BatchMode=yes -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -q server1  "if [[ $(/usr/bin/lsblk /dev/sde | wc -l) = 2 ]]; then echo found; fi"
```

But if I do it on the remote cli or using ansible `"if [[ $(/usr/bin/lsblk /dev/sde | wc -l) = 2 ]]; then echo found; fi"`, it will run.  I don't want to use ansible all the time since we only have tower and slow to do simple query.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

The command substitution `$(/usr/bin/lsblk ... )` is in double-quotes and the `$` is not escaped, so it'll be executed and substituted on the local computer before `ssh` is even executed. If you want that to be run on the remote system, either use single-quotes instead of double, or escape the `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer, put it in a script 1.sh,

ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o BatchMode=yes -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -q server  < 1.sh